# Iphone Movement in particular direction with particular speed

Tags: iphone

How can i find when iphone moving particular direction (i.e X axis) with particular speed  using its UIAcceleration values?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the phone is moving at a constant speed then there will be no acceleration, therefore the accelerometer will not be able to tell you.